# How to determine version of CoreCLR runtime from within application

Tags: .net-core

I noticed that my previously very stable web apps running in Azure App Service on .NET core started throwing new errors this week.

I suspect (and it is just a guess), that the .NET Core 1.0.1 shared runtime was installed on the Azure App Service this week and that my apps rolled forward to the 1.0.1 runtime as explained here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/13/announcing-september-2016-updates-for-net-core-1-0/

Going forward, I want to log what version of the Core Runtime to aid in troubleshooting.

**How can I determine from within my ASPNET Core web app what version of the core runtime is running (i.e. 1.0.0 or 1.0.1)?**

I've searched the entire Internet and even tried looking at the source code, but I can't find where (or if) this is exposed.

Comment: I am 100% sure they have discussed about that at corefx repo at GitHub. Use GitHub search to locate them please. Besides, you always deploy your app along with .NET Core bits, so why do you care about the version? It makes no sense.

Comment: I am using a framework dependent deployment, not a self contained deployment, so I am depending on bits that are installed on the machine.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/

Comment: I could pin it to 1.0.0 by packaging as a self contained app, or setting applypatches to false in [app].runtimeconfig.json, along with moving my platform dependency back to 1.0.0, but that isn't my question.  I want my log messages to show the coreclr version it is running under.

Comment: Clarification - you have to edit the runtimeOptions section in project.json to set applyPatches to false and that section gets copied to [app].runtimeconfig.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took sometime a while ago to dig deep into the code here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils/Muxer.cs

I ended up using something like this:
https://gist.github.com/npnelson/5bf49a145338120cacbac7ee8bd399bf

It's been working for me for awhile, but it seems like it could be pretty fragile as .NET Core evolves, so use with caution.

**Update 3/28/2018**
The dotnet team is actively tracking this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28132 Give it a thumbs up if you would like to see it become part of the API

**Update 3/1/2019**
This will be available as of .NET Core 3.0 Preview 4:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35573